# how to extract blue color hidden text between rows in table using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying to crawl all hidden comments  in table rows, after row 2 and 3, but fail to extract.

i have tried the below code to extarct these comments but fails.
below is my code.please help me someone to crack this problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment

import requests

r =requests.get('http://www.esuppliersindia.com/krishna-agro- 
  traders/aboutus-p17322178-u10731500-swa.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',class_='text-listing')

trs = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs[2:3]:

   print(tr.text)

for tr in trs[3:4].find_next_sibling('td'):

   print(tr.text)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this "blue coloured" hidden text? Do you mean the green commented out info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure though if you are looking after below comments inside table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment
import requests
r =requests.get('http://www.esuppliersindia.com/krishna-agro-traders/aboutus-p17322178-u10731500-swa.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',class_='text-listing')
comments=table.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
print(comments[0].split('</tr>')[0])
for i in range(1,len(comments)):
  print(comments[i])
```

I will print the output like that.

```
<td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11-b">No. Of Employees</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11">10</td>

<tr>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11-b">Export Turnover</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11-b">Annual Turnover</td>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11">10 </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11-b">Import Turnover</td>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text-f11"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text-f11-b">Bankers</td>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="text-f11">Hdfc Bank </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I want to extract one by one element but it is not working like that.

Comment: What do you mean it is not printing one by one?

Comment: it is printing one by one, but if i want particular tr tag elements i.e. 2 tds tag text ,that i am not getting.